# Combox Items from Colors Set Selected Item Programmatically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `comboBox` where items are Colors and I would like to set the default selected items.

For example at runtime I would like to set *Red color* as the selected item.

How can I achieve this? I tried setting the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` but no luck they don't work, I'm new in WPF.

Here's my code.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboColor" Width="50" Height="50">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**C# Code Behind**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ComboColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
   //not working
   ComboColor.SelectedItem = Colors.Red;
   //not working also
   ComboColor.SelectedValue = Colors.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
typeof(Colors).GetProperties()
```

returns a `PropertyInfo[]`, not a collection of `Color`  instances.

Add this to turn it into an IEnumerable of Colors:

```
ComboColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(null));
```

To use a collection of Colors instead of PropertyInfo in XAML, change the ItemTemplate to this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The color names will however get lost with this solution, and the ComboBox will only show #AARRGGBB values.

---

It would perhaps make sense to create your own ColorInfo class

```
public class ColorInfo
{
    public ColorInfo(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        Name = info.Name;
        Color = (Color)info.GetValue(null);
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public Color Color { get; }
}
```

set the ItemsSource like this

```
ComboColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties()
    .Select(p => new ColorInfo(p));
```

and bind to it with

```
<Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

With

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Name" ...>
```

you could write

```
ComboColor.SelectedValue = "Red";
```

With

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Color" ...>
```

this would work:

```
ComboColor.SelectedValue = Colors.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reflection to get [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netcore-3.1) instances from all properties in the type `Colors`. Since the `ItemsSource` is a collection of type `PropertyInfo`, you cannot just assign a `Color` as selected item. In fact, the selected item **has to be equal** to the corresponding instance in `ItemsSource`.

To make this work as intended, get the `PropertyInfo` instance for the color to be selected.

```
ComboColor.SelectedItem = typeof(Colors).GetProperty(nameof(Colors.Red));
```